# Android Studio memory profiler can not detect deallocations

Tags: android, android-studio, memory, profiler

I'm trying to use memory profiler on Android Studio to record Java/Kotlin allocations and the column that shows Deallocations show only zeros (0)... The deallocations info was working properly a couple of days ago and now just zero deallocations.
The problem was notice on the Android Studio 4.2.2, Artic Fox and Bunble Bee (Canary 9).

The app is runing on:
minSdkVersion 22
targetSdkVersion 29
On a Motorola One G(5) Plus with Android 8.1.0

I tryed on 3 different apps and 2 diferrent devices. Memory deallocations just gone...

Is there any configuration that I migth missing ?!?

[image]